# Cookie issues with .htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In the .htaccess file, I set a cookie `lang` with value `en` when someone visits `example.com/en` and redirect to `example.com`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en(.*) https://example.com$1 [L,QSA,CO=lang:en:https://example.com:/]

RewriteRule ^(fr)(?:/([^/]+))?$ $2?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

In my PHP, when someone visits `example.com/fr`, I set a cookie using

`setcookie('lang', 'fr', strtotime('+1 year'), '/');`

Then, when going to `example.com`, I use `$_COOKIE['lang']`, which should be `fr` in this case, however I see `en`.

Could the .htaccess be setting up the `en` cookie even if the url wasn't `example.com/en`?

Comment: You are not using the correct  flag attribute , **https://domain.com** should be **.domain.com** / means the entire site. (the cookie is available for entire site) You can replace / with /en so that the cookie is available for /en only.

Comment: The `lang` cookie with value `en` should not be available for `/en` only. It is needed when going to `example.com`, so I can show the English page. If it's `fr`, I can redirect to the French page. `/fr`.

Comment: So yes it should be available for the whole site.

Comment: Can you add the whole php code where you check the lang parameter and add the cookie?

Comment: When using Chrome Incognito, it started working. What's actually not working now is setting the cookie via `RewriteRule ^en(.*) https://example.com$1 [L,QSA,CO=lang:en:https://example.com:/]`